# Can't get mongoid working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4

[I followed the official tutorial](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html).

I have sqlite3 commented out in my Gemfile as well as the following lines:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

However, I keep receiving the 
`Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem "sqlite3" to your Gemfile.`

Reason seems to be that the database.yml still lists sqlite as the database. How am I supposed to get Rails to use the generated mongoid.yml? Replacing database.yml's contents with mongoid.yml doesn't seem to do the trick - I get the

`ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter` error.

Is it not compatible with Rails 4 or am I missing something simple?

Edit: I think I'm getting warmer. I've added the adapter as 'mongoid'. Here's the contents of my database.yml now:

```
development:
  adapter: 'mongoid'
  # Configure available database sessions. (required)
  sessions:
    # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: xboxie
      # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        # Change whether the session persists in safe mode by default.
        # (default: false)
        # safe: false

        # Change the default consistency model to :eventual or :strong.
        # :eventual will send reads to secondaries, :strong sends everything
        # to master. (default: :eventual)
        # consistency: :eventual

        # How many times Moped should attempt to retry an operation after
        # failure. (default: 30)
        # max_retries: 30

        # The time in seconds that Moped should wait before retrying an
        # operation on failure. (default: 1)
        # retry_interval: 1
  # Configure Mongoid specific options. (optional)
  options:
    #
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: xboxie_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0


# # SQLite version 3.x
# #   gem install sqlite3
# #
# #   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
# #   gem 'sqlite3'
# development:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/development.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
# test:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/test.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# production:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/production.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000
```

Produces the error:

`LoadError: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mongoid_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've solved this by adding:

```
Mongoid.load!(Rails.root.join("/config/mongoid.yml"))
```

to `config/intializers/mongoid.rb`, as per the tutorial.

Also you'll need to change the following line in your config/application.rb file from:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

to (in Rails 3.x):

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
# require "sprockets/railtie" # Uncomment this line for Rails 3.1+
```

or (in Rails 4.x):

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issues. All was resolved by recreating my app without ActiveRecord...

```
rails new app_name --skip-active-record
```

adding Gems as above and getting my mongoid.yml right...

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens when using mongo. Basically mongo does not go well with active record . So generate your application using the command,

rails g myApp --skip-active-record

Works well in my case

Answer (score 1):

Check your `config/database.yml`. You probably specified sqlite3 there.

Comment: Yes I have. However, if I change it to mongoid I have a whole mongoid.yml configuration file and a database.yml configuration file and I'm not sure how to swap the two

Comment: At the end of tutorial that you linked, they were talking about how to remove database.yml isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was receiving a similar error coming from puma. I realised then that on config/puma.rb I had:

```
on_worker_boot do
  # worker specific setup
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
        Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

I had to replace everything inside on_worker_boot with the content of config/initializers/mongoid.rb

In general, I think a good way of debugging this is to search for any reference to active_record on the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error as

```
"Could not load active_record/connection_adapters/mongoid_adapter".
```

I could solve it by commenting
    "config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load" in deveopment.rb and
    "config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true" in application.rb. Also make sure that in database.yml, database is not specified at sqlite3 but mongoid.
You will also need to remove "require 'rails/all'" from application.rb and replace it with

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

as mentioned in above comments.